# Functional dependencies (first steps)

Tags: sql, functional-dependencies

I'm practicing **Functional Dependencies**, i'm reading a book related to databases and they provided an example, it goes like this:

> A company performs all kinds of sales through different terminals
> (terminals for payment of debit and credit cards). These terminals
> belong to different sectors, from hypermarkets to simple candy kiosks.
> We are interested in knowing the business name, a contact telephone
> number and legal address, including City and State which are
> tabulated. The terminals have an identifier that distinguishes them
> and are sold to a single store (not reuse between different shops).
> The terminals also have an operating system. Each of the terminals
> have a certain amount of memory (in MBytes), manufacturing country
> (also tabulated) and year of importation. Terminals have a ticket
> reprint service, so they need to store the unique number of the
> terminal that made the sale, the invoice number associated with it,
> the date and time of the sale, the amount, the type of card (debit or
> credit), the card number and in how many installments the payment was
> made.

Obviously, they gave me a relationship; i have to work on it to obtain the functional dependencies, do you get me?

This is the relationship:

> Company(BusinessName, FantasyName, BusinessNumber, Telephonenumber,
> address, locality, locality_number, state, state_number, terminalid,
> operatingsystem, idCountry, Country, ImportationYear, idTicket,
> Billnumber, amount, CardNumber, Memory_quantity,
> date_and_time_of_sale, card_type, installments_quantity)

---

---

So, first of all i replaced the values of that relation; i used letters:

> Number of elements inside Company: 22

Then: Company(A, B, C, D, E, F, G , H, I, J , K, L M, N , O, P ,Q, R, S ,T, U, V)

Now, i have to find the dependencies, for example:

```
A -> B, C

E -> L, M, R

T -> U, V
```

Not really sure about this, can help me to define the functional dependencies?. I'm very confused :/

EDIT:

[image]

```
BusinessName 
FantasyName 
BusinessNumber 
Telephonenumber 
address 
locality 
locality_number 
state 
state_number 
terminalid 
operatingsystem 
idCountry 
Country 
ImportationYear 
idTicket 
Billnumber 
amount 
CardNumber
Memory_quantity 
date_and_time_of_sale
card_type 
installments_quantity
```

EDIT #2:

Functional dependencies:

```
BusinessNumber -> BusinessName, FantasyName, TelephoneNumber, Address, LocalityNumber, StateNumber, IdCountry

Terminal -> operatingsystem, idCountry, ImportationYear, Memory_quantity

Sales -> amount, CardNumber, date_and_time_of_sale, card_type, installments_quantity
```

Comment: Don’t use single-letters, that won’t help you at all because it completely masks the business (domain) purpose of those columns - and you need that “human information” to know how to improve the model. You can only use short names when the semantics of the column don’t matter (I don’t recommend ever using short cryptic names, actually)

Comment: Hey Dai, thank you for replying. I'm stuck on this example (i cannot move forward) because i was not able to complete the dependencies; i mean,i tried but it does not make sense to me at all. Can clear my mind?

Comment: Can’t you see that the amount of computer-memory in the terminal is completely independent of the business’ phone-number? That’s an example of a *non-dependency* that you can break-out. **Think about what each column represents in the real-world**.

Comment: Yeah, of course. What i'm trying to obtain is the complete structure of dependencies; this is my first time doing this and i need a good example that may help me to move on. Don't have a good example (not a good textbook).

Comment: Then get a better textbook :) - I’m not a fan of database-theory textbooks, guides and courses that place too much emphasis on modelling relations using academic terminology like “functional dependencies” and obsessing over 1-4NF. I’d rather they dove-in to 6NF and used less abstract terminology for beginners. Rather than saying “functional dependency” (which has nothing to do with functions nor functional programming) I’d say “Eliminate repetitive data”. That’s all there is to it (sort-of).

Comment: I know how to perform the 3NF (Normalization)but i got stuck defining the dependencies; that's why i made this thread :/

Comment: @Dai I have updated my thread. Can we do it together for this first example?, I dont want to make any mistake. I understand the normalization process but this part is the hardest to me :(

Comment: @Dai if i fail getting the functional dependencies then all the normalization would be bad,that's why i want to make sure (only for this time) that the functional dependencies are ok. Do you get me?

Comment: What is "FantasyName"? That isn't mentioned in the problem description.

Comment: FantasyName and BusinessName would be the same in this case

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems & algorithms you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs.

Comment: PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you're not sure it's right, ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1 - Identify "groups" of attributes:

Based on the flat list of attributes you provided, it can be seen that these attributes can be grouped by a logical/"real-world"/"business-domain" owner. For example, these attributes are "owned" by the real-world business entity:

```
BusinessName             Business
FantasyName              
BusinessNumber           Business
Telephonenumber          Business
address                  Business
locality                 Business (This attribute is redundant as locality_number serves the same purpose)
locality_number          Business
state                    Business
state_number             Business (This attribute is redundant as state_number serves the same purpose)
terminalid 
operatingsystem 
idCountry 
Country 
ImportationYear 
idTicket 
Billnumber 
amount 
CardNumber
Memory_quantity 
date_and_time_of_sale
card_type 
installments_quantity
```

And these are "owned" by the payment-terminal entity:

```
BusinessName
FantasyName              
BusinessNumber
Telephonenumber
address
locality
locality_number
state
state_number
terminalid                 Terminal
operatingsystem            Terminal
idCountry                  Terminal
Country                    Terminal (Should be renamed to "ManufacturingCountry")
ImportationYear            Terminal
idTicket 
Billnumber 
amount 
CardNumber
Memory_quantity 
date_and_time_of_sale
card_type 
installments_quantity
```

When I go through the list, I come-up with these groups:

```
BusinessName             Business
FantasyName              Business
BusinessNumber           Business (I assume this is a unique identifier, a "natural key")
Telephonenumber          Business
address                  Business
locality                 Business (This attribute is redundant as locality_number serves the same purpose)
locality_number          Business
state                    Business
state_number             Business (This attribute is redundant as state_number serves the same purpose)
terminalid               Terminal
operatingsystem          Terminal
idCountry                Terminal, Business 
Country                  Terminal, Business (This attribute is redundant as idCountry serves the same purpose)
ImportationYear          Terminal
idTicket                 Sale
Billnumber               Sale (What is the difference between `idTicket` and `BillNumber`?)
amount                   Sale
CardNumber               Sale -- NEVER STORE CREDIT CARD NUMBERS IN A DATABASE!!!!!
Memory_quantity          Terminal
date_and_time_of_sale    Sale
card_type                Sale
installments_quantity    Sale
```

### Step 2 - Convert to tables ("relations") and identify which attributes are keys (natural keys or synthetic keys) and which are just plain ol' data (dependent-data attributes)

```
CREATE TABLE Businesses (
    -- Natural key:
    BusinessNumber,

    -- Plain ol' data attributes (i.e. dependent attributes):
    BusinessName,
    FantasyName,
    TelephoneNumber,

    -- Business address fields (also plain ol' data):
    address
    locality_number,
    state_number,
    idCountry
)

CREATE TABLE Terminals (
    -- Natural key:
    terminalid,

    -- Plain ol' data attributes:
    operatingsystem,
    idCountry,
    ImportationYear,
    Memory_quantity
)

CREATE TABLE Sales (
    -- Natural key:
    idTicket,
    BillNumber,
    
    -- Plain ol' data attributes:
    amount,
    CardNumber,
    date_and_time_of_sale,
    card_type,
    installments_quantity
)
```

I also need to add tables for inferred entities, such as `Country` and `Locality` (in modern-day application development we generally don't reference states/countries by a synthetic-key (aka "surrogate-key") because it adds complexity without adding any business-value).

```
CREATE TABLE Localities (
    -- Synthetic key:
    locality_number,

    -- Plain ol' data attributes:
    Locality
)

CREATE TABLE Countries (
    -- Synthetic key:
    idCountry,

    -- Plain ol' data attributes:
    oCountry
)
```

### Step 3 - Add foreign-keys:

The `Sales` table needs to be revised so it can reference its related `Business` and `Terminal` records (this should have been done in Step 1 by identifying that `terminalId` and `BusinessNumber` are attributes of `Business`, `Terminal`, and `Sale`, btw - that's my mistake):

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    -- Natural key:
    idTicket,
    BillNumber,
    
    -- Foreign keys:
    CompanyNumber,
    TerminalId

    -- Plain ol' data attributes:
    amount,
    CardNumber,
    date_and_time_of_sale,
    card_type,
    installments_quantity

    CONSTRAINT PK_Sales PRIMARY KEY ( idTicket, BillNumber )
    CONSTRAINT FK_Sales_to_Businesses FOREIGN KEY ( CompanyNumber ) REFERENCES Businesses ( BusinessNumber )
    CONSTRAINT FK_Sales_to_Terminals FOREIGN KEY ( TerminalId ) REFERENCES Terminals ( TerminalId )
)
```

(And add `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in both the `Businesses` and `Terminals` tables to reference `Localities` and `Countries`)

Comment: I gave you the complete-list for `Business`. I won't give you the complete-list for `Terminal` and `Sale` because that would mean doing your homework for you - and because the answer is really self-evident from the `CREATE TABLE` statements I posted. If you can't derive it from what I posted then you're either short-on-sleep (as is typical for a student) or something is really wrong with you :/

Comment: Not that anything can be inferred from a name, but {x1,...} functionally determines {y1,...} when/iff there exists a function f such that for every row f(x1,...)=(y1,...). I'd agree that relations & normalization are poorly taught though.